# Fortran pass by reference pass by value homework

Tags: fortran, parameter-passing

I had a question on a hw that I got wrong and was wonder if someone could explain it. 
Don't worry class is over just wanted to know why it's wrong. I asked a few other student and they had the same answer I had as well. I also look on line but all the examples I found are swap functions the X=1 is confusing me.

```
    SUBROUTINE TEST(X,Y,Z)
    X=1
    Z=X+Y
    RETURN 
    END


    N=2
    CALL TEST ( N,N,M)

   WHAT WILL M BE IF PASSED BY REFERENCE?
   WHAT WILL M BE IF PASSED BY VALUE-RESULT?
```

I got 3 for the first and 4 for the second question.

Comment: This code itself is quite close to runnable.   Did you try just complete the program and run it with passing by value and passing by reference?    By default, all variables are passed by reference, but you can use the `value` attribute to pass an argument by value.

Comment: if passed by value, m is never defined., so you might get zero or some garbage.  If passed by reference, as it will be in fortran, the code is actually illegal.  I'd guess the x=1 ends up assigning both x and y to 1 and you get 2, but really the correct answer is "undefined".

Comment: [This recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20650284/2068635) might be of interest.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994360/passing-arguments-by-pass-by-reference-to-a-swap-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing by reference,
X=2, Y=2 when the subroutine is entered.
Then X gets set to 1, which will change Y to 1 as well since they share the same memory location, right? So that would make (X+Y) = 2  ==> Z = 2.
M=2.

By value:
X=2, Y=2, but then X get sets to 1 but that doesn't change Y since this is by value.  That makes Z = 3.
M =3.

Comment: Provided the compiler knows about the aliasing and reloads Y from memory before the assignment.

Comment: Right - there are a number of assumptions.

Comment: Compiled with gfortran, by reference indeed gives 2 for me. Though I thought Fortran is never aware of aliasing; it's one of the assumptions that makes it fast, isn't it?