# Is this legal in Fortran: dot_product(x, x)?

Tags: fortran

I saw this code on the Internet: `dot_product(x, x)` Is this "undefined behavior" in Fortran (because of the aliasing)?

Comment: Which bit of that are you questioning?  The function or the parameters?

Comment: @wallyk the aliasing of the arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no undefined behaviour there, the dot product of a vector with itself is well defined.  The function definition does not require any modification to the input arguments, it would be a bizarre implementation indeed which modified them.

The (2003 and 2008) standard's restrictions on arguments which overlap (or are *aliased* but that is not the language the standard uses) only apply if a procedure tries to redefine such an argument.  That is not the case with the intrinsic `dot_product` whose arguments, as defined in the standard(s), have `intent(in)`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tracked down what the FORTRAN 77 ANSI standard has to say about this:

**15.9.3.6 Restrictions on Association of Entities**

*If a subprogram reference causes a dummy argument in the referenced subprogram to
become associated with another dummy argument in the referenced subprogram, neither
dummy argument may become defined during execution of that subprogram. For
example, if a subroutine is headed by*

```
SUBROUTINE XYZ (A,B)
```

*and is referenced by*

```
CALL XYZ (C,C)
```

*the dummy arguments `A` and `B` each become associated with the same actual argument C
and therefore with each other. Neither `A` nor `B` may become defined during this execution
of subroutine `XYZ` or by any procedures referenced by `XYZ`.*

So the standard restricts the modification of the aliased arguments rather than their aliasing.

Comment: "neither dummy argument may become defined" means that you can't give a value to the dummy argument.  So aliased "input-only" arguments are OK.

Comment: I think that the relevant clause in the Fortran 2003 standard is 12.4.1.7 to which note 12.29 adds *If there is a partial or complete overlap between the actual arguments associated with two different
dummy arguments of the same procedure and the dummy arguments have neither the POINTER nor TARGET attribute, the overlapped portions shall not be defined, redefined, or become undefined during the execution of the procedure.*  The intrinsic `dot_product` doesn't *define, redefine or make undefined* it's arguments which, the standard also states, have `intent(in)`.

Comment: @M.S.B. Edited. Thanks! I thought it was just bad/awkward English on the part of the authors, and they really meant "undefined behavior happens here"